# Changing Font Family with Apps Script from Google Form to Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

Thank you for any help with this, this is the first time I'm using Apps Script. I created a Google Form to fill a header on a Google Doc. Everything has worked well except I'm looking to change the font family and font size for different elements of the header. I've tried a few things but I haven't found anything to work yet.

```
function autofillGoogleDocfromForm(e) {
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var firstName = e.values[1];
var lastName = e.values[2];
var position = e.values[3];
var building = e.values[4];
var phoneNumber = e.values[5];
var email = e.values[6];
var address = e.values [7];

var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1vCOrwCZAAQiiZmLgPi_74xy65ws8u1DqRW05eukgisI");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rFCugcmL8uLMeBwQSZ8FJ4Sol4bmpwa6");

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ' , ' + firstName, templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}",firstName);
body.replaceText("{{LastName}}",lastName);
body.replaceText("{{Position}}",position);
body.replaceText("{{Building}}",building);
body.replaceText("{{phoneNumber}}", phoneNumber);
body.replaceText("{{email}}", email);
body.replaceText("{{Address}}", address);

doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: try creating a style object and using setAttributes https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#setAttributes(Object)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please consider posting a answer to your question once you have a working solution.